# IOS - Add message to status bar

Tags: ios, core-location, statusbar

How to add message to status bar when I using geolocations. Like the image below

[image]

Answer (score 1):

As @Quentin Hayot described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32630267/ios-text-below-status-bar-while-app-is-in-background)

> This banner is displayed by iOS itself in the following situations:
>
> - A background app is tracking your position (after a startUpdatingLocation)
> - A background app is using your microphone
> - A background app is performing a VOIP call
>
> The banner color changes with the reason. There is no way to force iOS
>   to display those banners but by using one of the relevant background
>   modes.

If your app does not [tracking position,](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26528831/blue-banner-myapp-is-using-your-location-for-app-that-uses-location-services) [using microphone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16878991/hide-red-recording-status-bar-in-ios-app-when-not-recording) or performing a [VOIP call](https://www.twilio.com/blog/2015/08/a-swift-adventure-building-basicphone-with-twilioclient-part-2.html), you will not able to display that bar.

Comment: Ok, thanks... I used locations, but its not work.

Problem was in method requestAlwaysAuthrization()

I change to requestWhenInUseAuthorization() and status bar show message