# How to show the application info outside the application

Tags: ios, iphone

i am doing one application.In that i am getting required information from web services.And i need to use the same info in settings page.So now i need to show that info outside the app, in status bar or like we can see the calling info in green color when we minimise and go to some app.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32630267/ios-text-below-status-bar-while-app-is-in-background - dublicate

Comment: Possible duplicate of [IOS Text below Status Bar while app is in Background](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32630267/ios-text-below-status-bar-while-app-is-in-background)

Answer (score 0):

If I understanding your question right, you need a push message or a widget.